MS Windows Server 2019 and .NET Framework 4 ASP MVC App - Run on IIS 10 - LDAP
I have an ASP.NET MVC App on .NET Framework 4, and I would like to Deploy this app to MS Server 2019 with IIS 10. The same app is hosted on MS Server 2008 R2 STD with IIS 7.5
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>

When I use MS VS Prof 2019 + MS VS Prof 2010 (Includes LIB for MVC2 and MVC3) I can publish app to the new server and I see the app is logged as Server logged LDAP User
I use LDAP to auto login in browser, the problem is that LDAP works in the browser on the Server (where the app is located on IIS), but when I try to reach the app from the client side I get the Login window in browser. The same app works on IIS 7.5 and MS Server 2018 with no problem.
On the client side, if I try to auto-log to the website I get a login screen (if I try to login with my LDAP cred. the login screen disappears and reappears in a moment), in-app log file I see the app is logged Successfully, but I got still only this screen, on webserver app works with autologin

If I disable I get error (it is ok)

I think then I set everything right:
I use same LDAP User like login to server, and I have Permission set for Pool and Folder


I set also other parameters on IIS (Impersonation is DISABLED)


Miss I something?

Why enable directory browsing in the first place? What happens if you don't enable that, and why did you think enabling it was the correct action? And I can see in your first screenshot that you don't have ASP.NET 4.7 checked.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 403.14 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

I ran into integrating LDAP with Firewall issue before, after I have installed the latest windows updates. Error: The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user ABC SID (S-XXX) from address A.B.C.D to activate DCOM server. Please raise the activation authentication level at least to RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY in client application. it fixed after I upgraded the Firewall Version. I hope this info let you think about something else.
